Initiate download from Excel
I have a spreadsheet that contains a column of URL addresses to photos. I would like to download all or selected photos to a location on my computer that I specify. I'd appreciate any suggestions or solutions.
Thanks

You tagged this question [visual-studio-code] but did not mention VS Code anywhere. Why? What do you mean by it?

Pretty much any scripting language or shell can do this, and they'll all use pretty similar logic. The sticking points will be what OS you're using, and whether the language you're looking at can read Excel files. PowerShell, if you're using Windows, can do this. Alternatively, in the past I would have used a plugin like DownThemAll and the FireFox browser, saved the Excel spreadsheet as HTML, and run it through the browser, but I'd use PowerShell today. Perhaps adding more info to your question will make it better and help us help you better.

Because I'm not aware of any such native functionality, I would use Nushell - a command line/shell.
It can programmatically open the spreadsheet, get the values from the column, and then download and save the web-referenced files.
open test.xlsx | get Sheet1.column0 |
  each {|url| http get $url | save ($url | url parse | get path | path basename) }

To get and use a decent file name the URL is parsed and the path basename is used.

PowerShell can do this too, as can pretty much any other script/shell.

@music2myear other shells typically don't have native support for reading excel files.

PowerShell can.

@music2myear Not without first installing an additional module though, right? 1, 2 (both mentioned are not official but community modules)

Those are for if you don't have Excel installed on the computer, or perhaps they try to make improvements on the base features. AFAIK Office includes PS modules enabling this and has for some time.
